# Using unionbyname to merge 2 Df2 with different columns not working with spark 3.2.1

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

Hi I am trying to merge 2 FDs with different columns in spark and I came across
unionByName which allows property allowMissingColumns

I am actually facing issues while using it here is my piece of code

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = Seq(("1","[unassigned]"))
val DefaultResponseDF = data.toDF("try_number","assessment_item_response_xid") 

val data2 = Seq(("2"))
val DefaultResponseDF2 = data2.toDF("try_number") 
DefaultResponseDF.unionByName(DefaultResponseDF2, allowMissingColumns=True).show()
```

When I run this on spark 3.2.1 and scala 2.12 in databricks cluster getting this error

```
 error: not found: value True
 DefaultResponseDF.unionByName(DefaultResponseDF2, allowMissingColumns=True).show()
                                                                  ^
```

Let me know if I am missing anything in using this. I believe it is available in spark 3.1 onwards I am on spark 3.2 so that cant be the issue .
let me know if anyone faced this before

Answer (score 0):

Nvm it was because in  scala True does not work it should be true

```
DefaultResponseDF.unionByName(DefaultResponseDF2, 
allowMissingColumns=true).show()
```

This works